# libnuma.so and rpmlib(FileDigests) is needed by mysql-community-server-5.7.23

Tags: mysql, suse

suse-11 linux,mysql-server 5.7.23.i have installed mysql-lib,mysql-common,mysql-client.when i install mysql-server and the os tell me some dependencies is needed.Errors:

```
warning: mysql-community-server-5.7.23-1.el6.i686.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 5072e1f5
error: Failed dependencies:
        libnuma.so.1 is needed by mysql-community-server-5.7.23-1.el6.i686
        libnuma.so.1(libnuma_1.1) is needed by mysql-community-server-5.7.23-1.el6.i686
        libnuma.so.1(libnuma_1.2) is needed by mysql-community-server-5.7.23-1.el6.i686
        libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.12) is needed by mysql-community-server-5.7.23-1.el6.i686
        mysql-community-client(x86-32) >= 5.7.9 is needed by mysql-community-server-5.7.23-1.el6.i686
        mysql-community-common(x86-32) = 5.7.23-1.el6 is needed by mysql-community-server-5.7.23-1.el6.i686
        rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by mysql-community-server-5.7.23-1.el6.i686
```

i also try to install the numactl,and command line tell me that numactl is latest,so what can I do to resolve this problem.help me,please.